# Ubuntu boot hangs on Dell XPS 13 7390 2-in-1 with Intel i7-1065G7

Tags: boot, dell

I have a Dell's laptop (Model: DELL XPS 13 7390 2-in-1 laptop, Tag:F4V82Z2, with Intel's 10-gen CPU i7-1065G7, IceLake) that originally shipped with Windows 10 and I would like to dual boot it with Ubuntu 18.04.3. However, the boot always hangs and the laptop starts to be really hot.

### What I tried:

I downloaded Ubuntu 18.04.3 (and also Ubuntu 19.04) from https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop
Using Rufus-3.8 I made a USB boot drive (File system:Large FAT, Partition scheme: MBR).

### HW:

- I read online that USB-2 are not supported by Dell so I tried both USB-2 and USB-3 drives.
- I ran the BIOS hardware check scan - Passed.

### From within windows:

- Just to make sure, I updated Windows to have the latest updates.
- I downloaded Dell's update utility and ensure that I have the latest updates.
- I updated the BIOS with the latest firmware since Oct 3, 2019
- I ensured that Microsoft Bit Locker is suspended (although the disk is fully encrypted).
- I shrank the C drive to un-allocate 200Gb for the Ubuntu boot.
- I ensured that windows fast startup is disabled

### From BIOS:

- I tried to use secure boot enabled/disabled modes.
- I tried switching the SATA configurations from RAID to ACHI
- I ensured that only UEFI boot is enabled

After booting from the USB, the UBUNTU grab is opened and I choose "try ubuntu". Then, I am getting an error related to the ACPI tables. I edited the grab with the following configurations but the boot always hangs:

- nosplash debug i915.nomodeset=0 max_cstate=1 acpi=off
  i915.nomodeset=0 max_cstate=1 acpi=off
- nomodeset=0 max_cstate=1 acpi=off
- nomodeset=0
- max_cstate=1 acpi=off
- nomodeset=0 acpi=off

What can I do next?

Thanks.

Comment: Update: I found https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_2-in-1_(7390), by adding the modprobe.blacklist=intel_lpss_pci option I was able to load and install Ubuntu. 
However, now the installation cannot find the Wifi adapter.

Comment: thank you much, looks like they already have a Ubuntu version with everything working including touch screen out of the box : https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=dell-xps7390-ubuntu1910&num=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In grub press e, then add modprobe.blacklist=intel_lpss_pci in the Linux line after "---" and press f10. That will get you to the full os.. then upgrading to kernel 5.3 will fix the wifi. I read that there are other ways to fix the wifi, by copying the Intel drivers in /lib/firmware, but that did not work for me..

I haven't found a way to get the touchscreen to work yet.. I read something about it sitting behind the intel_lpss module and someone made a driver patch, whatever that is, to get it to work.. but I haven't tried to apply it, nor I know how to.. seems to be a c program

Answer (score 2):

Use 19.10 and it will work. I have the same computer. Also, touchscreen works almost perfectly in this version.

Comment: No. I'm trying and no success. I get the following error: stdin:invalid input

Comment: Did you use an image writer other than Rufus? They can cause weird issues.

Comment: The problem was that the USB stick was too large. I've tried a 32Gb stick first. Then tried a 8GB stick and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have a XPS 2-in-1 7390 with Ubuntu 19.10 and found these edits to work for me on boot:

Initial boot: add `nomodeset` to the linux line.

And then after you're installed, you need to edit `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

And then run `sudo update-grub`