# Dual booting Ubuntu 19.10 on Dell XPS 7390 fails at Dell logo

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, dell, xps

I'm having a fair amount of trouble getting Ubuntu to install on my new xps 13 (10th gen i7). So far I've created the bootable usb using Rufus with GPT partition format (also used MBR, still doesn't work), changed the SATA format to AHCI using these instructions (https://support.thinkcritical.com/kb/articles/switch-windows-10-from-raid-ide-to-ahci), disabled secure boot in UEFI and turned off bitLocker.

When I reboot my computer, I press F12 to access UEFI, I then select my usb with ubuntu on it from the boot device list, but when I then press exit, the computer gets stuck at the Dell logo screen and doesn't get any further. I've also tried adding a boot option, then selecting BOOT/EFI/grubx64.efi (or something like that filepath), but the same issue arises.

I appreciate this is probably a duplicate question, but I've been looking everywhere and can't seem to find any advice on this particular issue. Before it's marked as a duplicate to this question: [Ubuntu boot hangs on Dell XPS 13 7390 2-in-1 with Intel i7-1065G7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179924/ubuntu-boot-hangs-on-dell-xps-13-7390-2-in-1-with-intel-i7-1065g7), I'm not even able to get to the grub screen which allows you to try Ubuntu.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, fast startup is disabled in the Windows power options.

Comment: I verified it using the "verify download" tab on the ubuntu website, everything seems in order there.

Comment: I'm not hugely familiar with ubuntu.  Is there any difference in using those other versions?  Ideally I'd like to get plain old vanilla ubuntu working if possible.

Comment: I just made a usb with the latest Lubuntu on it, pressed F12 and selected the UEFI usb drive as the boot option, still the same issue.  Stuck on the Dell screen.  I also changed fastboot from minimal to thorough in UEFI and it's still not working

Comment: Now you've been introduced to the essence of troubleshooting; try something, think about what could be causing the problem, try something else. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: Well yes, but the issue is I've tried everything I can think of

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I figured it out.  Turns out that for this version of ubuntu, secure boot should actually be ENABLED, and the partition scheme when you make the bootable USB should be GPT if you have UEFI instead of BIOS.

I imagine some other issue will soon show up, but at least I can get to the grub screen now.

Comment: Strange. For me, secure boot is disabled. The system came with Ubuntu 18.04 provided by Dell, a freshly installed a 19.10 over it.